# Python + Nose - How to call a Nose/PyTest test method, from outside that TestClass dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pytest, nose

I am developing a Test Automation framework for my team, where in I have all the tests written in Python and Nose plugin.
The thing is - I need to call these tests dynamically from outside of this TestClass ina seperate Module. Reason to do this is, I am implementing a dynamic framework which will help test async APIs, and build the validation suite on the fly, as and when the APIs send response.

Coming back - I have thought of building a dynamic dictionary which consists of Modules, Class, Methods and Method parameters - something like below -

```
        [{
        "testModule" : "<module_name1>",
        "testClass" : "<class_name1>",
        "testMethod" : "<method_name1>"         
    },
    {
        "testModule" : "<module_name1>",
        "testClass" : "<class_name1>",
        "testMethod" : "<method_name2>"         
    }]
```

Using such a setup I intend to dynamically create the TestClass objects by using "import_module" to dynamically import the TestClass, and then call the test method using getattr().
My question is how to make this work in Nose/PyTest?